# I am using nextcord to make a bot and it worked perfectly but after a day it stoped working probely

Tags: python, discord, bots, nextcord

I was trying to make a command that sends the user's avatar

I used this code and it actully worked but now for some reason it doesn't:

```
@bot.command()
async def photo(ctx):
    await ctx.send(ctx.author.avatar.url)
    print(f'sent {ctx.author.avatar.url}')
```

I tried making an event and for somereason it worked??? I have no idea why it did that:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
         if '/photo' in message.content:
              await message.channel.send(message.author.avatar.url)
```

Comment: Is your question why the first code doesn't work anymore or why the second code works, or what? What do you even mean by "it worked" or "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem would be in the on_message()

First of all, that is not needed, you can either use slash commands to use `/`, or just set your prefix to be `/`

However if you *really* want to use that, you need to use `bot.process_commands()`, if you do not use this, your commands won't work

Answer (score 0):

do NOT use on_message() to write commands. Instead, use @bot.slash_command, as it is the most latest and most common solution. This is how it would work:

```py
@client.slash_command(name="photo", description="Get your profile picture")
async def photo(interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(content=interaction.user.avatar.url)
```

Hope all of this helped **ツ**